# smbfs/cifs won't mount

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

This `fstab` has worked for 4 Ubuntu versions.  All of the sudden, it doesn't work after a reboot, but I had it working under 12.04 yesterday. It still works on another 12.04 machine with no problems.

- `smbfs` is installed.
- Run `sudo mount -a` and it just sits there and thinks.
- Configuration:

  ```
  //hda/Music /home/ag/Music cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,noserverino,gid=1000,uid=1000,nounix,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0

  //hda/Pictures /home/ag/Pictures cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,noserverino,gid=1000,uid=1000,nounix,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0

  //hda/Movies /home/ag/Videos cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,noserverino,gid=1000,uid=1000,nounix,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0

  //hda/Docs /home/ag/Documents/Shared cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,noserverino,gid=1000,uid=1000,nounix,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0

  //hda/Torrents /home/ag/torrents cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,noserverino,gid=1000,uid=1000,nounix,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0

  //hda/Private /home/ag/private cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,noserverino,gid=1000,uid=1000,nounix,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0

  //hda/Books /home/ag/books cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,noserverino,gid=1000,uid=1000,nounix,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with updated packages from the Ubuntu repository, specifically:

```
libsmbclient:amd64 (3.6.3-2ubuntu2, 3.6.3-2ubuntu2.1)
smbclient:amd64 (3.6.3-2ubuntu2, 3.6.3-2ubuntu2.1)
samba-common:amd64 (3.6.3-2ubuntu2, 3.6.3-2ubuntu2.1)
samba-common-bin:amd64 (3.6.3-2ubuntu2, 3.6.3-2ubuntu2.1)
```

My error was not listed in the `changelog`, therefore it is feasible that a simple reinstall might be the only thing that was needed.