# Can't mount CIFS drive

Tags: 12.04, mount, cifs

I have a number of fstab entries that will no longer mount. They used to work under 10.04 and after I did a clean install of 12.04, they did work for a while although they would periodically hang up and become unresponsive until they were unmounted "lazily" and then remounted. Now, I can't mount them at all.

The shares all mount fine in nautilus.
When trying to mount commandline:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //target/share /shares/mount_point -o user=username,password=password
```

nothing happens. It just sits there; no error, no messages in the logs, no timeout(!) so far as I have left it trying (minutes). No messages come up in the remote computer's logs (Windows).

This appears to be the same problem that appears here:

[smbfs/cifs won't mount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129287/smbfs-cifs-wont-mount)

However, all my packages are up-to-date and higher versions than those listed in the solution to the above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue. On a fresh install of 12.04.2 It did work initially but now just hangs on multiple different servers. My /etc/fstab is the same as proposed above.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

The following is the line in my `fstab` file.

```
//192.168.2.2/MVP /mnt/movies1 cifs username=media,password=yourpassword,defaults  0 0
```

The following is the mount command I used.

```
sudo mount //192.168.2.2/MVP
```

I hope this helps!